# Observe stars with a cloudy sky

Tags: astronomy, stars

Is there any way to view the stars even in a cloudy sky? For example by using a particular camera, or a particular UV filter in front of the camera, and so on.

Comment: How far away from visible light can the wavelength be? Because radio telescopes routinely observe on cloudy days.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the liquid water absorption spectrum across a wide wavelength range:

[image]

As long as you are not observing from from space, there is always some water vapour along the line of sight to a star. Depending on the thickness of the cloud cover and the brightness of the stars, it may be possible to view some of the stars.

[Relevant Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water)

Comment: More important is the variation of the cloud. With a perfect uniform and constant cloud we could observe a star if any tiny amount of signal gets through. In reality the variation in the cloud makes this difficult.  In the near IR there is always a varying bright background due to light from O-H bonds which makes even a 'clear' sky challenging

Answer (score 0):

for a cloudy sky, Mie scattering is playing the role. to see a star you have to use larger wavelength :

[image]

but the ordinary cameras are not sensitive in IR ($\lambda$ >900 nm)
as a rule of thumb, the larger the wavelength the easier way to image through the particles.

Comment: probably you mean shorter, why longer? For example, a RADAR can see through clouds because the wavelengths are much shorter than visible light.

Comment: Radars use longer wavelength than visible light (cm to meter).
its simple, shorter wavelength means in a specific length there are more electric field than the longer wavelength.
 and this means there are more interaction and more scattering and wave can not propagates simply.

Answer (score -2):

You need an app to see the stars in a cloudy sky.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer.